# asyncLocalStorage loses context in error middleware?

Tags: node.js, express, middleware

I am trying to use `asyncLocalStorage.getStore` in an `errorMiddleware` after the application throws an error. I noticed that `asyncLocalStorage.getStore` was returning the right context right before the throw.

But if I add a try-catch around the throw, `asyncLocalStorage.getStore()` would return the right context. Wondering if context is loss through the error middleware